# How to make container with an image and multiple Text inputs?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container with an image, and I am trying to add text to the side of that Image, like in the picture below, but I cannot. Can anyone help?

```
 body: ListView(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 500,
        color: Colors.white24,
        height: 125,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 265.0),
          child: Image.asset('images/HPerm.png'),
        ),
      ),
      Text('HI')
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

I tried making a simple container, but I am having trouble adding the many Text inputs and I am not sure how to make the image move over to the left.

Comment: Try with your some efforts and post some code. Just posting the quesition is not a good practise here in SO. Please refer [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I know I should have posted the code, but I had deleted my attempts.

Comment: It has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Flutter or struggle on the concept of [Flutter Widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets) then I suggest you divide (and conquer) the image (the widget you want to achieve) in smaller pieces. What I´m seeing is a Container (or a Card) with a row of (2) widgets. The first it´s an image (NetworkImage or AssetImage) and the second it´s a Column with many childrens nested.